# Accessing last element of a list using python string formatters

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, types, string-formatting

Is there a way to access the last item in a list within a string formatter expression? What I am aiming for is something like this

```
>>> my_list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
>>> print('last item: {0[-1]}'.format(my_list))
last item: 5
```

However above's example will result in a `TypeError` since the `-1` is interpreted as a string. This example obviously could have been written as

```
>>> print('last item: {0}'.format(my_list[-1]))
```

but in more complex cases the situation might be as follows

```
>>> print('first item: {0[0]} last item: {0[-1]}'.format(my_list))
```

or

```
>>> print('something: {0.something} last item: {0.my_list[-1]}'.format(my_object))
```

where I do not want to specify the list or even the object I am addressing in the placeholders every time.

In python 3.6 this could be solved using f-Strings by a formulation like this

```
>>> print(f'{my_list[-1]}')
```

but how, and this is my question, can this last list element addressed in the a formatter expression in earlier python versions (e.g. 2.7 or 3.5) too?